# distinct background gradient

Tags: css

I want my website background to have the top 55% be one color and the bottom 45% to be another color.  Based on the tutorial [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/linear-gradients/#.UgQMhPnV-Gw)  (I am using green, 80% and 20% to make the size difference easier to spot)

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 20%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 20%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,     rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 20%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,     rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 20%);

background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%,     rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 20%);
background-color: green;
```

But it's a bit hard to follow and I am unable to get the functionality I want.  Right now, it repeats the gradient all the way down the screen but I do not know why.  Removing the second rgba() entries breaks it entirely and that was the only trail I thought to follow.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply this background to the `body`, make sure to add this css :

```
html {height: 100%;}
```

Otherwise, the body won't take the entire page height.

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3M3w/2/)**